# Copy stdout to stdin between java prcesses

Tags: java, process

I try to copy one stdout of a process to the stdin to two new processes. But somehow this does not work as expected and is suprisingly hard to debug. What am I missing here?

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process pA = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-version").start();
        Process pB = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "cat").start();

        InputStream stdErrA = pA.getErrorStream();
        OutputStream stdInB = pB.getOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream cmdInB2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        OutputStream tee = new TeeOutputStream(stdInB, cmdInB2);
        IOUtils.copy(stdErrA, tee);
        pA.waitFor();
        stdInB.close(); // EDIT: results mostly in the expected behavior, but throws IOException broken pipe sometimes
        pB.waitFor();

        String resultOfBOut = IOUtils.toString(pB.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        String copyOfAOut = cmdInB2.toString("UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? your code doesn't have a good logic.

Comment: What classes are `TeeOutputStream` and `IOUtils`? Those aren't in the standard library.

Comment: True they are from Apache commons io

Comment: ErrorStream isn't an InputStream, I think that line 6 is wrong

Comment: cmdInB2 always will be empty, you don't use before to try to get a string from it in the last line

Comment: @DBQ just because java version prints to stderr, no the stream is not empty. interestingly a stdInB.close() between the two wait for, wokrs some time as expected. other times it thows a broken pipe exception

Comment: Try adding a `tee.flush()` after the `IOUtils.copy` and before the `pA.waitFor`.

Comment: @vanOekel that does not help. the second process is just sitting on the input stream and waits for ever

Comment: Odd, I tested on Windows (replaced bash/cat with a python script) and it works fine. Maybe you can try on not-Windows but with the Python script? I placed my code in a gist: https://gist.github.com/fwi/b48f6b7c377715e0edb8e7fabff3d49e